# How to use ascii code to cipher caesar in java to rotate each character by 13 places

Tags: java, string, encryption, ascii, caesar-cipher

How to use ascii code to cipher caesar in java to rotate each character by 13 places example-if entered sentence is abcd it should display nopq i cant get from letter n to z it shows question mark. 
**The Program**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class caesarcipher
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner ga=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a text to be ciphered");
    String s=ga.nextLine();String cc="";
    int l=s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<=l-1;i++)
    {
      char c=s.charAt(i);
       int n=(int)c;
       if(c!=' '&&c!='!'&&c!='?'&&c!='.')//to check for special characters
       { 
          if(c>'A'||c<'M'||c>'a'||c<'m')
           {
              n=n+13;//to mo
              char f=(char)n;
              cc=cc+f;
          }
        }
      if(c!=' '&&c!='!'&&c!='?'&&c!='.')
          {
          if(c>'N'||c<'Z'||c>'n'||c<'z')
          {
              int p=(int)c;
              p=p-13;//toget value 13 times behind
              System.out.println(p);
              char f=(char)p;
              cc=cc+f;
            }
         }

        else
        {
            cc=cc+c;
        }
    }
     System.out.println("The ciphered text is : "+cc);
   }
}

//output of my program=  Enter a text to be ciphered stuvwxyz-The ciphered                    //text is : ?f?g?h?i?j?k?l?m
```

//THe in tended output=fghhijklm

Comment: `(c>='A'&&c<='M'||c>='a'&&c<='m')` and similarly for N-Z.

Comment: What is your program outputting now? Is it throwing any errors? Please be more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: If you want to implement Caesar's cipher, I'd suggest using "modulo" operation instead of several `if` statements: convert character to its number in alphabet (`(int)some_char - (int)'a'`), add 13, take modulo 26 (`id_in_alphabet` is encoded with `(id_in_alphabeta+13)%26`), then convert it back (`(char)(id_in_alphabet + (int)'a')`).